# android app crashs when i try to post json data to a web service

Tags: java, android, json, http, post

Hi everybody i'm trying to Send data from my android app to a web service in a json Object  but the application crashs when i click the send button any one can help me to slove my problem ? thx , Below is my main java code :

```
public  class MainActivity extends Activity  {

private Button send;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   send= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
   send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            JSONObject jsonobj; // declared locally so that it destroys after serving  its purpose
            jsonobj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                // adding some keys
                jsonobj.put("name", "toto");
                jsonobj.put("twitter", "twito");
                jsonobj.put("country", "totoland");                     
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                //buildref.setText("Error Occurred while building JSON");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost("bbqhmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
            StringEntity se = null;
            try {
                se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
            httppostreq.setEntity(se);
            try {
                HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
 }
}
```

this is the LogCat :

```
    08-08 15:11:51.790: I/Process(24024): Sending signal. PID: 24024 SIG: 9
    08-08 15:12:34.440: W/dalvikvm(24321): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught                             exception (group=0x41d3e700)
  08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
  08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
 08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
 08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
 08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:518)
08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
```

08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
   08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):     at com.example.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
   08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):     at com.example.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
   08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   08-08 15:12:34.510: E/AndroidRuntime(24321):     at   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)

Comment: show yout LogCat ouput

Comment: Please provide some logs

Comment: why don't you use AsyncTask or separate thread for sending json data ??

Comment: You are calling WS in main thread it will make network main thread exception .So try to call your ws asynchrounously in background

Answer (score 1):

you are sending your data from main UI thread. try to send data using AsyncTask<>
like this

```
public  class MainActivity extends Activity  {

private Button send;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



send= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // execute like this way
         new HttpAsyncTask().execute("bbqhmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");


 });
}


  private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

           JSONObject jsonobj; // declared locally so that it destroys after serving  its purpose
               jsonobj = new JSONObject();
               try {
                   // adding some keys
                    jsonobj.put("name", "toto");
                    jsonobj.put("twitter", "twito");
                    jsonobj.put("country", "totoland");                     
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    //buildref.setText("Error Occurred while building JSON");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost();
                StringEntity se = null;
                try {
                    se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
               httppostreq.setEntity(se);

                    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    if(inputStream != null)
                         result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    else
                         result = "Did not work!";

      return result;
    }

   private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        return result;

    }

}


        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //you will get result here in "result"
       }
    }

}
```

i have edited your code but you may need to corrects its format
this is how i am using in my way

```
    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {



            return POST(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
    public static String POST(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("name", "jaimin");
        jsonObject.accumulate("country","ind");
        jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", "yoooo");

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();



      // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
   // 11. return result
    return result;

  }

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

  }
  public boolean isConnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
         return true;
      else
         return false;  
 }
```

Comment: I replaced it in my project , but it still don't work (crash after click ) this is my LogCat Window

Comment: 08-08 14:23:01.965: W/dalvikvm(9285): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d3e700)
08-08 14:23:01.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9285): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Comment: My mistake .. Jst find and edit to this ` HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(urls[0]);`

Comment: i did it but still have the same problem :/

Comment: Post your logcat in your question

Comment: Now it stop Crashing after i delete the last try block , But now i checked if the Web service has received the data , but i found nothing in the webservice Side

Comment: your crash is because your way of receiving input is wrong.

Comment: see my edited answer i ve implemented code to receive response

Comment: i think the problem is that eclipse don't accept httpclient.execute() and httpresponde.getentity() without surrinding with try and catch , and then the problems begins and it crashes again

Comment: i am using ` httpclient.execute() ` along with whole code in single try catch block

Comment: do you want to refer my code to send json data? then i might post it

Comment: OK jaimin thank you for the code i paste it , but if you can test it with this url : bbqhmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet :  and tell me if you got any result here: http://hmkcode.appspot.com/post-json/index.html , because i did and nothing was added ..

Answer (score 0):

```
Read about runOnUiThread. Call this runThread() method name into the onCreate().
private void runThread(){
 runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost("bbqhmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
        StringEntity se = null;
        httppostreq.setEntity(se);
        try {  se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
               se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
               se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
               HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Android's Volley. http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html
It simplified a lot of things for me.